# YouTube can't remove share, watch later and channel

Tags: youtube

Not sure if something changed in YouTube API but with a new website when I embed a video I always get the share, watch later and channel image

Can't find a way to hide them

Not working in code snippet not sure why

```html
<iframe id="vid-player-1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Youtube revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#Revision_History) states that `showinfo` parameter is deprecated as of September 25, 2018. It was used to hide video title and uploader info.

> Following the change, the channel avatar and video title will always display before playback begins, when playback is paused, and when playback ends. The avatar being displayed is new behavior that will be consistent across all embedded players.

Unfortunately it seems that "Watch Later" and "Share" buttons are part of this feature and they can't be removed.